# linux + how to change disks name to other names

Tags: linux, rhel, udev, disk, block-device

we have disk devices as  ( on redhat machine version 7.2 )

```
sdb
sdc
sdd
sde
```

we want to change the names to

```
vxb
vxc
vxd
vxe
```

is it possible

expected results

from lsblk output we need to see

```
vxb
vxc
vxd
vxe
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not expect you will be able to do that without changing the Linux kernel as `/dev/sd*` are a matter of Linux kernel. And `lsblk` uses data from kernel (sysfs, to be precise) and `udev` as a device daemon.

You can however make symlinks, that create `/dev/vx*` you want. For that I suggest symlinking based on UUID or label by referencing `/dev/disk/by-label/<label>` or `/dev/disk/by-uuid/<UUID>` as /dev/sd* may change between boots. Please note that this will not change the `lsblk` output.

Either way, the answer might be helpful if you'll explain why you are trying to rename the disks as this is quite an unusual request.